# Using multiple IF statements in stored procedure with different parameters call on Linq C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, stored-procedures

Is it possible to use a stored procedure in c# because I've tried it on VB.net when I can setup its parameters that only needed let's say I have a stored procedure like this:

```
    ALTER PROC [dbo].[StoreProcedure_Test01]
    (    
        @Param01 nvarchar(35) = NULL,
        @Param02  smallint = NULL,
        @Param03 char(21) = NULL,
        @Param04 datetime = NULL,       
        @Type bigint
    )    
    WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
    AS
    BEGIN    
    SET NOCOUNT ON;        
    BEGIN TRY    
        BEGIN TRANSACTION;
        IF @Type =1
        BEGIN
          SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3 From TABLE00 Col00 = @Param2           
        END
        IF @Type = 2
        BEGIN
          Select * FROM TABLE01 where Col01 = @Param1 and Col04 = @Param03
        END
END
```

Now in my C# Codes calling out store procedures I do like this:

```
var query = (from i in LinQ.StoreProcedure_Test01(Param01, Param02, Param03, Param04, 1) where i.Col00 == 1 select new { AA = i.Param01, AB = i.Param02 });
```

Now on the parameters I place a 1 for the if statement in the stored procedure the problem is that if I select it in gave me the 1st if statement return data only now if I do like this:

```
var query = (from i in LinQ.StoreProcedure_Test01(Param01, Param02, Param03, Param04, 2) where i.Col00 == 1 select new { "ALL TABLE" });
```

put an 1 parameter for the if statement in stored procedure it still gave me the same return data from the 1st if statement and it ignores the second if statement is there a way I can use a stored procedure for c# with multiple condition and parameters needed specially when I use a virtual table it also ignores it. is it possible?

Just to add up some of my prev deeds i tried doing this on vb.net by using ado.net framework.

```
Try
            cmd = New SqlCommand
            da = New SqlDataAdapter

            cmd.Connection = con
            cmd.CommandText = "[StoreProcedure_Test01]" 'this is your store procedure
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

            With cmd

                .Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Param01", SqlDbType.NVarChar))
                .Parameters("@Param01").Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
                .Parameters("@Param01").Value = Parameter01

                .Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Param02", SqlDbType.NVarChar))
                .Parameters("@Param02").Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
                .Parameters("@Param02").Value = Parameter02

                .Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Param03", SqlDbType.NVarChar))
                .Parameters("@Param03").Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
                .Parameters("@Param03").Value = Parameter03

                .Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Param04", SqlDbType.NVarChar))
                .Parameters("@Param04").Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
                .Parameters("@Param04").Value = Parameter04

                .Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Type", SqlDbType.Int))
                .Parameters("@Type").Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
                .Parameters("@Type").Value = 1

            End With
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Return True

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Finally
            cmd.Dispose()
        End Try
```

as seen above its flexible coz i can add parameters as same as the store procedure conditions i've made all i want to know is that when it comes to c# linq is it possible to do this? :(